# What does "kicked up" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

This sentence is from a [novel](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ojkGAwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y):

> Georgie could hear him sitting back in his chair. She could picture him, too--long legs **kicked up**, resting on the edge of their shared desk.

What does *kick up* mean? I couldn't find the meaning in the dictionaries, but does it sound like what it is that he is kicking his leg upwards and rests it on the desk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it means that his feet are resting on the edge of the desk & at a glance it might look like he's in the middle of a kick - legs in the air - but he's really stationary.

This phrase is not meant to be taken literally (in the sense of the act of kicking), but is more used to be evocative.

[image]

Comment: I suspect the *legs kicked **up*** usage may derive (or at least, have gained traction) from [*kick **back** and relax*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7793/), which itself probably owes something to ***sit** back and relax*.

Comment: Worth noting that *kick up your heels* is an idiom which means relaxed and happy!